# static id's dynamic price Workcube - Coldfusion

Tags: dynamic, coldfusion, static, product

I want to set static id(product) and its dynamic price, if the id's price changes it will be displayed correspondingly, that's all I want, but I don't know the variable nor the structure of the queries and outputs, I don't know how to define the specific product's price in workcube using Coldfusion, this is as far as i've gone:
And i know that the script below is wrong ^.^

```
   <cfquery>
    SELECT
        PRICE_STANDART.PRICE PRICE
    FROM
        PRICE_STANDART
    WHERE
        PRICE_STANDART.PRODUCT_ID = #product_id#
</cfquery>
    <cfset product_id = 612>
    #TLFormat(price_standart)#
```

Comment: I am trying not to be rude, but it sounds like you don't have even the most basic of web development skills. You should start by taking some lessons or reading some books. In particular, it sounds like you need to learn about SQL (http://www.amazon.com/SQL-Dummies-Allen-G-Taylor/dp/0470557419/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1294405543&sr=8-1) and the basics of ColdFusion (http://www.amazon.com/Adobe-ColdFusion-Web-Application-Construction/dp/032166034X/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1294405443&sr=8-3)

Comment: @adam tuttle, u don't have to repeat me myself, as i wrote, i dont know much bout this cold fusion, just wanted the answer, i know that i have to learn everything from the books, but it will take too much time, once i get answer, i will learn much faster from it @Ciaran Archer this is the ooold system for big companies, that provides everything like site etc.

Comment: what I'm telling you is that you're trying to run before you've learned how to walk. You might be able to go for a bit, but you'll eventually trip and hurt yourself. Your question essentially boils down to, "How do I query a database and display the results in ColdFusion", which is entirely too broad a question and a 101-level topic that is covered in the beginner-section of any CF training, including books.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think the following will work with your example:

```
<cfset product_id = 612>
<cfquery name="price_standart" datasource="#variableNameWithDatasourceName#">
SELECT
    PRICE_STANDART.PRICE PRICE
FROM
    PRICE_STANDART
WHERE
    PRICE_STANDART.PRODUCT_ID = 
    <cfqueryparam value="#product_id#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">
</cfquery>
<cfoutput>#LSCurrencyFormat(price_standart.price, "international")#</cfoutput>
```

[cfqueryparam](http://cfquickdocs.com/cf9/?getDoc=TLFormat#cfqueryparam), while not necessary, prevents SQL injection attacks and serves as a bind variable with the JDBC driver.

[LSCurrenyFormat](http://cfquickdocs.com/cf9/?getDoc=TLFormat#lscurrencyformat) will format a numeric value as currency. `TLFormat()` is a not a built-in ColdFusion function.